# How can you run singular parametrized tests in pytest if the parameter is a string that contains spaces?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a test that looks as following:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('param', ['my param', 'my param 2'])
    def test_param(self,param):
        ...
```

This works fine when calling this test with

```
python3 -m pytest -s -k "test_param"
```

However, if I want to target a specific test as following:

```
python3 -m pytest -s -k "test_param[my param]"
```

I get the error message

```
ERROR: Wrong expression passed to '-k': my param: at column 4: expected end of input; got identifier
```

Also, when my input string contains a quotation mark `'`, I get the error

```
ERROR: Wrong expression passed to '-k': ... : at column 51: expected end of input; got left parenthesis
```

and if my string contains both `"` and `'`, I am completely unable to call it with the `-k` option without the string terminating in the middle.

How can I run tests with string parameters that contain these symbols? I am currently creating a dict and supplying `range(len(my_dict))` as the parameter so I can access these variables via index, but I would prefer to be able to directly enter them in the commandline.

EDIT:

The current suggestions are all great and already solve some of my problems. However, I'm still not sure how I would call singular tests if my test function looked like this (it has more than one entry as opposed to this minimal example):

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('input, expected', 
            [
                (
"""
  integer :: &
    my_var                                                                                            !< my comment
""",
{'my_var': 'my comment'}
                )
])
def test_fetch_variable_definitions_multiline(input,expected):
    ...
```

Comment: for complex parameter sets you can use `id` of pytest param. Please try out solution from my answer below and let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to your question including "EDIT" section:

You can use following syntax to run pytest

```
pytest .\tests\test_package_1\test_module_1_1.py::TestClass111::test_1111["param_name"]
```

where `param_name` can be both value of single parameter or `pytest param id`

To assign some id to parameter set you can use following syntax:

```
class TestClass111:
    @pytest.mark.parametrize(
        "param_1_name, param_2_name",
        [
            ("Some difficult param 1", {"a": 1}),
            ("Some difficult param 2", {"b": 2}),
        ],
        ids=["id1", "id2"]
    )
    def test_1111(self, request, param_1_name, param_2_name):
```

or

```
class TestClass111:
    @pytest.mark.parametrize(
        "param_1_name, param_2_name",
        [
            pytest.param("Some difficult param 1", {"a": 1}, id="id1"),
            pytest.param("Some difficult param 2", {"b": 2}, id="id2"),
        ],
    )
    def test_1111(self, request, param_1_name, param_2_name):
```

so you can access test with param set with id=`id1` like this:

```
pytest .\tests\test_package_1\test_module_1_1.py::TestClass111::test_1111["id1"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Wow. This was an interesting rabbit hole to go down.

You need to access the test you want to run via its nodeid. Node ids are assigned by `class::method::param`.

But your param has spaces, and that makes it hard to pass in via the shell. I ended up using this to figure out what the node ids actually are:

```
import pytest
import os

@pytest.mark.parametrize('param', ['my param', 'my param 2'])
def test_param(param):
    print (os.environ["PYTEST_CURRENT_TEST"])
```

That gave me this for output:

```
so.py:7: RuntimeError
- Captured stdout call -
so.py::test_param[my param] (call)
```

Which is not terribly dissimilar to what you tried to pass in via the shell, and that already failed. But that is the nodeid. A small bit of testing later, and this seems to work:

```
~ % python3.9 -m pytest so.py::test_param\["my param"]
= test session starts =
platform darwin -- Python 3.9.2, pytest-7.2.0, pluggy-1.0.0
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

so.py .                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            [100%]

= 1 passed in 0.01s =
```

Answer (score 1):

The [-k option](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/example/markers.html#using-k-expr-to-select-tests-based-on-their-name) can use `and`, `not` and `or` in the expression

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('param', ['my param', 'my param 2'])
def test_param(param):
    print(param)
```

With `python -m pytest -s -k "test_param[my and param]"`

```
collected 2 items / 1 deselected / 1 selected

test_file.py
my param
.
```

With `python -m pytest -s -k "test_param[my or param]"`

```
collected 2 items

test_file.py
my param
.
my param 2
.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `class::method[param1-param2-param3]` construct in your command

```
#The python file test_2.py contains

import pytest
import os
class Test_SmokeTests:
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("param1,param2",
                             [
                                 ("a1","a2"),
                                 ("p\"1","p\"2"),
                                 ("p'1","p'2"),
                                 ("p 1","p 2")
                             ]
                             )
    def test_smokeTest(self, param1, param2):
        print("param1 - ", param1)
        print("param2 - ", param2)
```

It works for each of the 4 sets of parameters i.e. with no spaces, with ', with " and with spaces.
It also works for multiple paramters. In this case, the parameters need to be separated by a dash (-)

```
pytest -s test_2.py::Test_SmokeTests::test_smokeTest["a1-a2"]

pytest -s test_2.py::Test_SmokeTests::test_smokeTest["p\"1-p\"2"]

pytest -s test_2.py::Test_SmokeTests::test_smokeTest["p'1-p'2"]

pytest -s test_2.py::Test_SmokeTests::test_smokeTest["p 1-p 2"]
```

```html
C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\py38\Scripts>pytest -s c://dev/Projects/deep-QA-Frontend_Pycharm/Deep_FE_TestAutomation_local/Tests/Playground/test_2.py::Test_SmokeTests::test_smokeTest["p 1-p 2"]
========================================================================================================== test session starts ===========================================================================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.8.13, pytest-7.1.2, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: c:\
plugins: html-3.1.1, metadata-2.0.2, xdist-3.0.2
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

..\..\..\..\..\dev\Projects\deep-QA-Frontend_Pycharm\Deep_FE_TestAutomation_local\Tests\Playground\test_2.py param1 -  p 1
param2 -  p 2
.

=========================================================================================================== 1 passed in 0.06s ============================================================================================================

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\py38\Scripts>pytest -s c://dev/Projects/deep-QA-Frontend_Pycharm/Deep_FE_TestAutomation_local/Tests/Playground/test_2.py::Test_SmokeTests::test_smokeTest["p'1-p'2"]
========================================================================================================== test session starts ===========================================================================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.8.13, pytest-7.1.2, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: c:\
plugins: html-3.1.1, metadata-2.0.2, xdist-3.0.2
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

..\..\..\..\..\dev\Projects\deep-QA-Frontend_Pycharm\Deep_FE_TestAutomation_local\Tests\Playground\test_2.py param1 -  p'1
param2 -  p'2
.

=========================================================================================================== 1 passed in 0.04s ============================================================================================================

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\py38\Scripts>pytest -s c://dev/Projects/deep-QA-Frontend_Pycharm/Deep_FE_TestAutomation_local/Tests/Playground/test_2.py::Test_SmokeTests::test_smokeTest["p\"1-p\"2"]
========================================================================================================== test session starts ===========================================================================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.8.13, pytest-7.1.2, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: c:\
plugins: html-3.1.1, metadata-2.0.2, xdist-3.0.2
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

..\..\..\..\..\dev\Projects\deep-QA-Frontend_Pycharm\Deep_FE_TestAutomation_local\Tests\Playground\test_2.py param1 -  p"1
param2 -  p"2
.
```

[Check the results here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5z2Z.png)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to use `-k` with string that contains spaces.

How about adding pytest built-in `ids` parameter (which allows you to control the naming of your parametrized tests) and configuring it like this:

```
import pytest
import logging as log


test_data = ["my param 1", "my param 2"]

def rpl_space(text: str):
    return text.replace(" ","_")

@pytest.mark.parametrize("param", test_data, ids=rpl_space)
def test_spaced(param):
    log.info(param)
```

pytest will then create tests that don't have spaces in names.

Here is an output of how pytest 'sees' it using `--co` flag (which only collects tests):

```
$ pytest tests/test_params_spaced.py --co
collected 2 items                                                                                                                                  

<Module tests/test_params_spaced.py>
  <Function test_spaced[my_param_1]>
  <Function test_spaced[my_param_2]>
```

and then I am able to run a single test like this:

```
$ pytest -k test_spaced[my_param_1]
tests/test_params_spaced.py::test_spaced[my_param_1] 
------------------------------------------------------------------ live log call -------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO     root:test_params_spaced.py:12 my param 1
PASSED
```